# I need to build an array with items that are determined in a loop using a variable.

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Hello and thank you for looking at this. I am at the limits of my ability and want to figure this out, so I am sorry if this is a newb question.

I am using a word press loop and assigning the first div element an ID using this...

```
$this_page_id=$wp_query->post->ID;
$item_id = $post->post_name;
```

and in the div...

```
<div id="<?php echo $item_id ; ?>"></div>
```

What I am looking for is at the end of the loop I want to build an array with each id in the array starting from the first id to the last.

So if there were 3 of the dive elements with the id st with $item_id like this...

```
<div id="item-1"></div>
<div id="item-2"></div>
<div id="item-3"></div>
```

my array would look like this...

```
$items = array("item-1","item-2","item-3")
```

After that I would use a foreach loop to split them up and run conditions on them, that part I get, it is the building the array that has me stumped.

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction, would like to learn how to do this as it might be handy in the future.

Thank you again and I apologize if this is to simple a question to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop, use the following code;

```
$items[] = $item_id;
```

which will add the item as new value in the array `$items`.

An array variable with a blank key (nothing inside the square brackets `[]`) simply assigns the value to the next available (numeric) key, but you don't have to worry about the key when traversing the array later.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So What I had to do is but an empty array before the loop and then add your code to the loop and it works print_r gives me exactly what I was looking for!

Thank you very much for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = array();
$items[] = $item_id;
$items[] = $item_id2;
$items[] = $item_id3;
```

and in your div it will look like this

```
foreach($items as $value){
<div id="<?php echo $value ; ?>"></div>
}
```